# Using static methods and static classes in web applications - Should it be avoided?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, memory-leaks

We have a MVC application with a traffic of about 800 users per day, lately we have observed that our App Pool is getting stopped on its own. Going to the logs we have found MemoryOutOfException. We were not able to figure it out why this might be happening so we did a code review. During code review we found out that we have static classes, static methods / Extension methods. We don't have any static variables and we are using  using block to dispose DbContext.
So is it possible that our static class/ static methods be the reason for memory issues ?

How are instances created inside static methods and classes disposed ? Are they collected by GC ?

Please suggest what more can we do to figure out the issue.

**EDIT**
Sorry for not sharing any code.
I want to understand the lifecycle of static class in web application. Can they create problem if I am doing complex operation that takes memory ?

For example if I translate my Domain model to View Model inside my static class like so :

```
public static class PersonTranslator{

     public static PersonVM (this Person p)
     {
           return new PersonVM{
               Name = p.Name,
               //etc...
               //lots of property here
           }
     }


}
```

Is it a good practice or I should just use normal classes rather going for 
extension methods. Can code like this create issues ?

Thanks

**EDIT 2:**
Our db context is implemented in base class and all the data access class derieve from it. I think (and I may be wrong ) that something is wrong here.

```
 public class DataAccessBase : IDisposable
    {

        protected ApplicationDataContext dataContext = null;

        public DataAccessBase()
        {
            dataContext = new ApplicationDataContext();
        }


        public DataAccessBase(ApplicationDataContext dataContext)
        {
            if (dataContext == null)
                dataContext = new ApplicationDataContext();

            this.dataContext = dataContext;
        }



        ~DataAccessBase()
        {

            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
        protected  virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // free managed resources
            }
            // get rid of unmanaged resources
            if (dataContext != null)
            {

                dataContext.Dispose();

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: How can we ever answer this without seeing any code?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-system.outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp.net.aspx

Comment: @GertArnold : Sorry for not sharing any code. Please see my edit

Comment: That's just a stateless factory. No problem. I'd look at the life cycle of your contexts.

Comment: @GertArnold : Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with our data context implementation class. Is it fine ?

Comment: Ok, so your `DataAccessBase` class implements `IDisposable` and the implementation looks correct. Good. But is your application set up to call `Dispose` after every usage of data access? If not, when do you call it? The part of the application that is responsible for creating an instance of `DataAccessBase` is also responsible for disposing it.

Comment: @NightOwl888 : We have Controller layer, Business Layer and DataAccess Layer. Our DataAccess Layer classes  inherits from DataAccessBase later the fetched result/s which are instances of our dbContext classes  are passed to BL and Controller Layer. We never explicitly call Dispose anywhere in application. Can this be the issue ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, this is likely the issue. `DbContext` should be disposed explicitly.

Comment: @nightOwl888 : Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly it could be anything:

- How much RAM does your server have?
- How many other sites are running on the server?
- How extensively are you using caching?
- What kind of session storage are you using and what are you allowing users to store in a session?

At this point, Id suggest profiling your application with the Performance Wizard. Typically though you would have done this prior to production and have instrumented your application because how else can you decide what size server / VM your app needs?

[image]

> .NET memory allocation gives you insight into the memory management of
>   your application because it analyzes every object in memory from
>   creation to garbage collection. The monitor can work in two different
>   ways. The first and less impactful is through sampling. It can also
>   take a much deeper look through instrumentation where code is added
>   into the binary to keep track of memory work.

You could also consider using Performance Counters and perfmon on the server. At the very least you should be getting alerts prior to the AppPool being dropped.i.e. at 80% of capacity for example.

It might even be that there is no "code" problem. You may have just underestimated what kind of resources are required to run your site (factoring in growth patterns) because as above without performance profiling pre-production it could have only have been a guess as to what you actually need.